# ArcMap - Blocky/Shattered Glass DEM Fix?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem

I am currently working with some data obtained from the Spanish Government to produce Digital Elevation Models for a site I am studying. I want to create a model that is essentially showing the changes in elevation smoothly, but when using the 5m DEM's provided, I am faced with a "terracing" (see image) effect upon the maps. Is there a way to remove this such that the data are more continuous?

[image]

Comment: NB: This is with a hillshade effect - I am trying to make an effect such that the terracing does not appear.

Comment: Try changing the re-sampling option under the display tab for the layer property?

Comment: Hi, I have done this (to bilinear interp) but no joy. I think it is due to the data being 16-bit integer as opposed to floating point 32 bit. The data come as .asc files so I may have gone wrong somewhere during initial processing.

Comment: Do you want it look better or be more accurate? If aesthetics are you goal you could try running Resample tool to a finer resolution (smaller pixels) if you have the right licence level. Since elevation are "continuous" data rather than "discrete" data you'd want to avoid the Majority and Nearest resampling techniques.  Try also "Filter" (Low Pass method) and "Focal Statistics" as smoothing tools

Comment: What is the projection of your raster data?

Comment: Solved! It was basically due to the nature of the data when it was converted from ASCII to raster. I had previously used the INTEGER conversion function, using FLOAT means the terracing has now disappeared. Thanks for all the help regardless!

Comment: You should write that up as an answer and tick as such so others know that a solution was found, rather than having to trawl all these comments.